# Access Route with direct link not show props Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am using React Route. When i type link in url box in browser then enter it is not show props of component.

When I click Link tag and component show props, but when i refresh page then it disapper. 
I need to click link again to show

my route

```
<Route 
    path='/employee-record' 
    exact
    render={() => (
        <EmployeeTable
            listEmployee={listEmployee}
            currentEmployee={currentEmployee}
            listRecord={currentEmployeeRecord}
            setCurrentEmployee={this.setCurrentEmployee}
        />
    )}
/>
```

it's only show prop when i click this, but when i type url to url box it's not

```
<Link to="/employee-record">Employee Record</Link>
```

Comment: do you use server side rendering?

Comment: @Domino987 no i am not

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but, if you are using a custom Webpack config maybe you have to add this configuration in the webpack.config.js file

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that these props ```listEmployee={listEmployee}
            currentEmployee={currentEmployee}
            listRecord={currentEmployeeRecord}
            setCurrentEmployee={this.setCurrentEmployee}``` are not passed from the parent compoent in some way?

Comment: `<Route path='/employee-record' exact
                    render={() =>
                      <EmployeeTable
                        listEmployee={listEmployee}
                        currentEmployee={currentEmployee}
                        listRecord={currentEmployeeRecord}
                        setCurrentEmployee={this.setCurrentEmployee}
                      />}
                  />`
I think my component is not render if i am not click this link.

Comment: then i want it will render when i type link in url box, but i dont know how to do it